# jQuery clone() leaves user data in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjCz3/

html

`<table>
       <tr class="copyMe">
           <td><input type="text" name="test" /></td>
       </tr>
   </table> <a id="clickMe" href="#">Click Me</a>`

jquery

```
  $('#clickMe').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();

   var tr = $('.copyMe:last');
   var newTr = tr.clone();
   newTr.appendTo(tr.parent());
  });
```

If you type text in the input, and click the click me, the row (including the input) is cloned and inserted - and has the data you entered.

The API for clone() says:

> The .clone() method performs a deep copy of the set of matched
>   elements, meaning that it copies the matched elements as well as all
>   of their descendant elements and text nodes. For performance reasons,
>   **the dynamic state of form elements (e.g., user data typed into input, and textarea or user selections made to a select) is not copied
>   to the cloned elements.** The clone operation sets these fields to
>   their default values as specified in the HTML.

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

So why does my input have the value filled in, and more important, how can I prevent it? I want them to be empty/default like the documentation implies. I tried specifying both arguments as false even though they default to that, and it still copies it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working with inputs that aren't checked or have values set on page load. ( or you want defaults that are set)...cache a row before user touches one . Then clone that stored row to append when needed

```
/* store row on page load*/
 var tr = $('.copyMe:last').clone();
 $('#clickMe').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();

  var newTr = tr.clone();....

})
```

Comment: This makes the most sense for my situation - and works great in the fiddle. Doesn't work on my page so it's probably some conflicting events but I think this is definitely the way to go. Thanks!!

Comment: np...always easiest starting with clean stuff

Comment: The problem in my page is it won't add more than one new row... weird. Edit: Actually it looks like it does add the new row, it just overwrites the last row it added.
3rd edit: Got it. Thanks for your good idea

Answer (score 2):

As far as a way to clear it yourself.

```
$('#clickMe').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var tr = $('.copyMe:last');
  var newTr = tr.clone();
  newTr.find('input').val('');
  newTr.appendTo(tr.parent());
});
```

**Update**

```
newTr.find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
newTr.find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bjCz3/3/

Comment: Thanks, this worked great for the inputs. For the checkboxes I'll have to do something different I guess, and dropdowns. I'm disappointed that I'll have to write lines for each form field type, when the docs say this behavior should happen anyway.

Comment: Actually, what I want is for the fields to be whatever value they were originally - so if they had a default value, to use it. I'm going to see what happens if I just clone the form field itself.

Comment: @Jessica check my update.  When you say you want the fields to be what they were originally are you referring to the `select fields`?

Comment: I meant any field - so if a checkbox was checked, it should be checked in the new row, etc. I think the above answer about cloning it before they touch it is best. - but thank you for your update!

Answer (score 1):

Do it yourself after filling a bug report at jquery:

```
  $('#clickMe').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var tr = $('.copyMe:last');
   var newTr = tr.clone();
   newTr.find(":input").val(''); //find all input types (input, textarea), empty it.
   newTr.appendTo(tr.parent());
  });
```

Updated working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjCz3/2/

Comment: This doesn't work, even if I use "input" or ":input" - try it in the fiddle?

Comment: `.empty()` only works on if your clearing parent elements not necessarily values.

Comment: True, I misused .empty() instead of .val('')